# How to properly generate relative signalr hub Url for a javascript client in a razor pages app

Tags: javascript, signalr, razor-pages

I have a signalr hub working in a .NET5 razor pages web app.  It's route is configured like so:

```
endpoints.MapHub<myHub>("/streamMyHub");
```

In the javascript on the razor page, I'm connecting with the following code:

```
connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl("/streamMyHub").build();
```

That all works just fine when I'm running using IISExpress at the site root level (http://localhost/streamMyHub).  My issue comes into play when I want my app to also support running as a nested app off the root like under IIS (so it would then be http://localhost/whatever/streamMyHub).

I can obviously resort to javascript, parsing the location.pathname or some such, but is there no Url helper/util method I can call that would properly generate it?  Should I add an additional/new route to the same hub url and use an MVC Url route helper or something?

Any info would be appreciated.

UPDATE:
It's just occurred to me, I can use the PathBase of the request, but is that really the proper solution?
.withUrl("@HttpContext.Request.PathBase.Value" + "/streamMyHub")